# ajax type : patch is not working 400 (Bad Request)

Tags: javascript, ajax, api, rest

i'm trying to update data in my local database server using ajax query in client server with api but it's not working i always get this error

```
jquery.min.js:4 PATCH http://127.0.0.1:3000/todo/62ff7276c2776726906f49d9 400 (Bad Request)
```

and this my code

```
const _update = (docId,itemId,content) => {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'PATCH',
        url: docId + "/" + itemId,
        data: {content:content},
        contentType: 'application/json',
        success: function (response, textStatus, xhr) {
            console.log(response)
        },
        error: function (xhr) {
            console.log(xhr);
        }
     });
}
```

i tested my api by postman and it worked perfectly , this id my router

```
router.patch('/todo/:id', async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const id = req.params.id
        const todo = await Todo.findByIdAndUpdate(id, req.body, { new: true })
        if(!todo)res.status(404)
        res.send(todo)
    } catch (e) {
        res.status(400).send(e)
    }
})
```

Comment: You set the contentType to `application/json` but you're not sending JSON.

Comment: which type i should set ?